# git remove file from upstream (github) repository

Tags: git, .htaccess

I inadvertently pushed an .htaccess file from my local to my upstream (github.com) repo. I do not want my team to have this .htaccess file as it will break their local environment. Is there a method to delete this file from the upstream repo?
After I realized the file was pushed I go into my local and

```
 git update-index --assume-unchanged magento/.htaccess
```

however I cannot delete the file from my local, that would break my local environment.

Comment: Could you just move it temporarily (so it appears as deleted), add the file to the `.gitignore`, commit the deletion and the updated `.gitignore`, and then re-add the file?

Comment: Daniel can you put this into an answer which i will accept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this helps you:

1. Move the file temporarily (so with a `git status` it appears deleted).
2. Add the file to your `.gitignore`.
3. `git commit` the file deletion and the updated `.gitignore` and push the changes to your remote repository.
4. Re-add the file to your local repository.